# How can I feed a server side Django string array into a client side JavaScript array?

Tags: django

On my server the array appears as follows:

```
data = [u'Data1', u'Data2', u'Data3']
```

In Django, I send the data through to the client using:

```
render(..., {'data': data})
```

On the client side I try to render in JavaScript using:

```
{{data}}
```

and get:

```
[u&#39;Data1B&#39;, u&#39;Data2&#39;, u&#39;Data3&#39;]
```

How can I fix this encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `safe` escape the string inorder to work fine

```
{{data|safe|escape}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass your data as a `json` object. In your `view.py`

```
from django.utils import simplejson
...
render(...{'data':simplejson.dumps(data)})
```

and then in your javascript function

```
var data = JSON.parse({{data}})
```

But as @karthikr already said, `|safe` is your case absolutely sufficient.